# Misunderstanding of small function in php

Tags: php, sql-server, return

Can anyone explain me step by step this function? My another code is not working, that's why I think I do not understand this funtion. Code below is the misunderstand function.

```html
<?php

public function sql_exec($query)
    {
        $query = trim($query);
        
        if($this->result = db_query($query, $this->con_id)) 
        {
            $this->row_count = db_num_rows($this->result);
            return TRUE; //what it returns exactly??
        }

    }
?>
```

Here is how i understand function(Connection done to MS SQL). Do not know what exactly mean return true, is it same as sqlsrv_fetch_array?

````````html
<?php
$serverName = "Host";
$params = array();
$cursorType = array("Scrollable" => 'keyset');
$connectionInfo = array("UID"=>"usernam", "PWD"=>"pass", "Database"=>"db", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sqlstr1 =sqlsrv_query($conn,"my uqery",$params,$cursorType);   
$count=sqlsrv_num_wors($sqlstr1);

```````return TRUE;(written in code above)````` what it reutrns?
 Is it same as SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY?

?>
````````

Comment: it returns the boolean value "true". which means that the query executed successful.

Comment: Thank you for reply.

Do you mean it is cheking if query execute and check if there row with these data, if yes than returns true?

Is it same as `if(sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$params))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

public function sql_exec($query)
    {
        $query = trim($query);

        if($this->result = db_query($query, $this->con_id)) 
        {
            $this->row_count = db_num_rows($this->result);
            return TRUE; //what it returns exactly??
        }

    }
?>
```

The code above returns BOOLEAN value TRUE if the query is executed successfully. But it seems the function is not called on your given example.

Comment: It is called in different file. It looks like 
`$cdb->connect("MainDB");
$sqlstr1="query";  $cdb->sql_exec($sqlstr1);` I do not want to use function and want to use sqlsrv_query instead of sql_exec, Is it same?

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov, you may use "sqlsrv_query" but remember that it doesn't return TRUE if query is executed successfully. Instead, it will return an object (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php)

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov, In any case, I guess I've answered your question. Can you accept it or upvote it? :)

Comment: Yes, you answered for my question and thank you very much! :)